# GFlags Stop on hung GUI

Tags: windbg, windows-kernel, gflags

Today I was wondering why the GFlags option *Stop on hung GUI* appears in the *Kernel Flags* tab of the GFlags user interface. Does the kernel have a GUI which could hang?

So I tried to get some information from Microsoft, but [MSDN just says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558818%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Stop on hung GUI flag appears in GFlags, but it has no effect on Windows.

So I wonder even more: a kernel flag for a kernel which has a GUI, but it's not the Windows kernel?

**Although it seems not of practical use, can anyone explain this?**

I also tried to get more information from WinDbg `.hh !gflag`, but it doesn't even give the statement that this won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kernel flag` indicates flag takes effect immediately `without requiring a reboot`

`Registry flag requires a reboot` for the flags to take effect

the kernel does not have any gui that could hang.

the term windows doesnt mean kernel but the gui windows of the running application

check NtSetSystemInformation  in your os to understand why 0x8 does not take effect

basically there are a few hardcoded magic numbers inside this api which tests each request for GlobalFlag changes and allows them or disallows them 
in xp-sp3  this magic value is `0B2319BF0` so any flag that is < 0x10 will be disallowed 
and stop on hung gui  is 0x8 so it isnt effective and you cant set this from registry tab

so effectively no way of setting this flag

```
nt!NtSetSystemInformation+0x193:
80606009 8b03            mov     eax,dword ptr [ebx]  ds:0023:001285f8=00000008  <---- +shg
8060600b 25f09b31b2      and     eax,0B2319BF0h  < magic value in nt 
80606010 8945a0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-60h],eax ss:0010:fb569cf0=00000000
80606013 8b0d6c125580    mov     ecx,dword ptr [nt!NtGlobalFlag (8055126c)] ds:0023:8055126c=00000000
80606019 81e10f64ce4d    and     ecx,4DCE640Fh  <--another magic value  both these magic values orred together 
will be 0xffffffff covers the whole range of flags 
8060601f 0bc1            or      eax,ecx
80606021 8945a0          mov     dword ptr [ebp-60h],eax ss:0010:fb569cf0=00000000
80606024 a36c125580      mov     dword ptr [nt!NtGlobalFlag (8055126c)],eax ds:0023:8055126c=00000000
```